# Dotvvm - fire custom binding handler after DOM elements are rendered

Tags: dotvvm

Lets say I want to customize css classes of treeview component.

HTML code for `<li>` expand. As we can see, 1st `<li>` got class `bp-state-expanded`. When its collapsed, I would like to have `bp-class-collapsed` class instead of `bp-state-expanded` for my styling purpose.

```
<li class="bp-item bp-state-focused bp-state-expanded" data-bind="css: $bpControl.getItemStyle($data)">
    <!-- ko if: HasCategories -->
    <a role="button" class="bp-expand">
    <i class="bp-icon fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></a>
    <a role="button" class="bp-collapse"><i class="bp-icon fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></a><!-- /ko --><label>
        <!-- ko if: $bpControl.canBeChecked($data) --><!-- /ko -->
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        <span><!-- ko text: Name -->Jazyky<!-- /ko --></span>
    </label><!-- ko template: { name: $findTemplateId("levelTemplate"), data: (AssignedToMenuItem) } --><!-- ko if: $data && $data.length -->
    <ul class="bp-list" data-bind="foreach: $data">

    </ul><!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

For my testing purpose I made this simple script where I want to store children DOM elements into variable. When I refresh page and my script is fired, treeview elements are not yet rendered.

I tried to use `afterRender` in data-binding but without any success. Is there a way how I can fire this handler after all DOM elements are rendered so i can manipulate with css classes?

```
ko.bindingHandlers["test"] = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

    var data = bindingContext.$data.AdminMenuList();
    var parentDOM = element.children;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (item) {
        if (item().HasCategories() == true){
            console.log(item().Name());
        }           
    });
}};
```

My data-binding in business pack treeview

```
<bp:TreeView DataSource="{value: AdminMenuList}"
         SelectedValues="{value: AdminMenuSelectedList}"
         ItemKeyBinding="{value: Id}"
         ItemHasChildrenBinding="{value: HasCategories}"
         ItemChildrenBinding="{value: AssignedToMenuItem}"
         Changed="{command: RedirectTo()}"
         Validation.Enabled="false"
         data-bind="test: {afterRender: test }">
<i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
<span>{{value: Name}}</span>
```

**UPDATE**

For now I solved that using `timeout` function, but not sure if this is good aproach.

[image]

I got 3 types of `li`. I will try to explain each type.

Type 1. => Its expandable element and the reason why I need `bp-class-collapsed` is that, because I dont want to influence `li` type 2,3 with `:not selector` and I need here `+` icon.

Type 2. => Its classic `li` with redirect so i need `o` icon here. If I will use `:not selector` here, it will influence also this type.

Type 3. => Same as type 2, but its nested `li`.

I hope its better explained on this sample.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? We don't have `bp-state-collapsed` class because you can use `:not(.bp-state-expanded)`.

Comment: I updated question with better explanation. I hope it will be more understandable

Comment: I see, you need a specific CSS class for collapsed nodes that are expandable. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported to apply custom CSS classes directly on nodes. But we will add the requested CSS class in next release. For now, you can modify our API to do what you want.

```js
let TreeView = DotVVM.BusinessPack.Controls.TreeView,
originalGetItemStyle = TreeView.prototype.getItemStyle;

TreeView.prototype.getItemStyle = function(item) {
    let style = originalGetItemStyle.call(this, item);
    style["expandable"] = this.hasChildren(item);
    return style;
};
```

Please beware this is our internal API and it may change in future releases. In most cases, you should use your CSS classes inside the ItemTemplate.